# gsubfn on data frame

Tags: r, regex, gsubfn

Search-and-replace an element in a data frame given a list of replacements.

**Code:**

```
testing123tmp <- data.frame(x=c("it's", "not", "working"))
testing123tmp$x <- as.character(testing123tmp$x)
tmp <- list("it's" = "hey", "working"="dead")
apply(testing123tmp,2,function(x) gsubfn('.', tmp, x))
```

**Expected Output:**

```
      x        
[1,] hey   
[2,] not  
[3,] dead
```

**My current output:**

```
     x        
[1,] "it's"   
[2,] "not"    
[3,] "working"
```

Been looking around for possible solution in chartr and gsub, but would like simplicity (short coding) given multiple gsub is required for such operation. Also my variable tmp can be scaled to many-pair replacement such that:

```
tmp <- list("it's" = "hey", 
            "working"="dead",
            "other" = "other1",
             .. = .. ,
             .. = .. ,
             .. = .. )
```

**Edit/Update #1:**

- would also like solution in gsubfn above and data-framed

Answer (score 4):

The issues are these:

- The dot only matches one character so it will never match an entire string unless that entire string has one character and therefore no name in `tmp` will ever be matched.  Use `".*"` to match the entire string.   If you wanted to match words, i.e. there are possibly several words separated by whitespace in each component of `x` so that for example one component of `x` might be `"it's not"` and we still wanted to match `it's` then use `"\\S+"`. There are other variations one could imagine as well and this gives a framework that encompasses many of them.
- the third argument to `gsubfn` can already be a vector and `gsubfn` will iterate over it so it is not necessary to use `apply`. (It will still work with `apply` but it is unnecessary.)
- to keep everything in a data frame one easy way is to use `transform` as shown below (or alternately use `transform2`, also in the gsubfn package). The `x` will automatically refer to the `x` column in the `testing123tmp` data frame and `transform` will produce a new data frame not overwriting the original.  If you want to keep these separate assign the result of `transform` to a new name or if you want to overwrite `testing123tmp` then assign it back to `testing123tmp`.
- we can use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to avoid generating character columns.

  ```
  testing123tmp <- data.frame(x=c("it's", "not", "working"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  ```

Thus we can reduce the code to:

```
transform(testing123tmp, y = gsubfn(".*", tmp, x))
```

giving the following data.frame:

```
        x    y
1    it's  hey
2     not  not
3 working dead
```

If we wanted to overwrite the `x` column rather than keep separate input and output columns we could have used `x = ...` in the `transform` statement instead of `y = ...` .

Comment: Beneath your phantastic packages and `R` books I even learn a lot on SO. Thanks, +1.

Answer (score 2):

You may write

```
gsubfn(".*", tmp, testing123tmp$x)
# [1] "hey"  "not"  "dead"
```

and then

```
testing123tmp$x <- gsubfn(".*", tmp, testing123tmp$x)
```

As for your approach, there was no need for `apply` as `gsubfn` is vectorized over that parameter, and the problem was to match only `.`---one symbol, while `it's` and `working` are of varying length.

However, if you are replacing one word with another word, then there is no need for regex. For instance,

```
idx <- testing123tmp$x %in% names(tmp)
testing123tmp$x[idx] <- unlist(tmp)[testing123tmp$x[idx]]
```

should work faster. If the task is more involved, then I guess

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(testing123tmp$x, unlist(tmp))
# [1] "hey"  "not"  "dead"
```

should be more robust than `gsubfn` as you don't need to deal with patterns like `.*`.